# Why don't make a Pay version of stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Offering actual money as a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty)
>   [Pay money to SO for quick support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57850/pay-money-to-so-for-quick-support)
>   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42326/cash-bounty-for-quick-programming-tasks-or-questions
>   [indicate in faq that SO is not rent-a-coder](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20120/indicate-in-faq-that-so-is-not-rent-a-coder)

A weird question I think, but I think it could be a business.
If I ask "what is the basic algorithm of a Tetris game" in stackoverflow, soon there must comes out answers, and I can solve my question in free.
But what if I ask "I need a Tetris game code in Objective-C, in 3D", is there anyone gonna answer me, in free?
How about I pay 50 bucks? Probably there gonna be someone come to answer it, at least more likely than I don't pay.

so, how about this idea

Comment: What is this I don't even...

Comment: stackoverflow should be always free, in my opinion.

Comment: How about we pay for reputation? Maybe then someone will a chance at beating Jon Skeet...

Comment: Then you basically have expertsexchange. Please don't!

Comment: Go to experts-exchange.com if you want to pay money.

Comment: There is a principle that is discussed in a lot of books on building communities and user created knowledge-bases that discuss how money actually poisons the community, and ends up optimizing for worse content and worse producers.  There are communities that succeed based on money, but they run a very different system.  Stackoverflow could not, and would not, succeed if money was tied into the process more than it is now.

Comment: You might be more interested in this site: http://www.rent-acoder.com/

Comment: @abe-Miessler experts exchange seems to be a one-sided market, which means the company decides which topics they cover. They also don't share the answers with the general public.

Comment: @adam-davis can you point me to a few of those books? I know from books like Predictably Irrational that mixing paid and community support is a risky idea (although Linux is partially built with paid labor), but I'm not so sure if a fully commercial peer2peer system wouldn't work.

Answer (score 9):

There are definitely sites that do that. stackoverflow is a QA site. You ask a question, and you get it answered (hopefully). However "I need a Tetris game coded in Objective-C, in 3D" is not a question, that's a job! This type of site would be where you can post your freelance project, your budget, and you'll get a number of people saying they'll do it (or asking for more money).

Something like this would be [oDesk](https://www.odesk.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you understand the concept of StackExchange. StackOverflow and the other StackExchange websites are where programmers, professionals and enthusiasts go to ask and answer questions about their areas of expertise. Each StackExchange website has a specific topic area. Questions which don't fit into that particular site's topic, are summarily closed, migrated, or deleted.

On no StackExchange website is it appropriate to ask for someone to hire - except [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com). On Careers, you can post a CV or look for prospective employees. (That said, I'd even mark this as [status-completed] or [status-bydesign], but that's just me.)